# Notification Center like view in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to show/hide a custom view on top of an iPad application like similar to how the Notification Center appears.

Initially a small drop down arrow appear on top So when the user swipe down it from the top and it will reveal the whole view and finally when user swipe to top position it will hide that view.

How to do this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but be careful with downward swipe gestures, especially on iOS 5.  It could be interpreted as a gesture for Notification Center.

Comment: You shouldn't do things which imitates the iOS-Features too much.

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t tried myself, but the following UIView subclass seems to do what you want:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/pullableview

EDIT:
I ended up trying it and works great.